# Integral Representation of Terminating Hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions

For Hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(a_1,a_2;b_1;z)$, if $a_1$, $a_2$ are negative integers, it will be terminated and convergence is not a problem. Under this circumstances, does anyone know the integral representation of the Hypergeometric function? In particular, what if $b_1=\frac{1}{2}$.The only integral representation I searched out applies uniquely to $Re(b_1)>Re(a_2)>0$:
\begin{equation}
{}_2F_1(a_1,a_2;b_1;z)=\frac{\Gamma(b_1)}{\Gamma(a_2)\Gamma(b_1-a_2)}\int_0^1dt\, t^{a_2-1}(1-t)^{b_1-a_2-1}(1-zt)^{-a_1}
\end{equation}

But it doesn't apply to the negative integers when $b_1=1/2$.

Comment: Contour integral representations: like 15.6.3-15.6.5 [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6).

Comment: @L.G.:Thanks a lot.